# FDT5 and port 7935

Tags: android, air, port, fdt

i have a strange issue. I have FDT5 Max at work and FDT5 free at home. With Max i can create a new Air for Android project, with free i just can create a Mobile AS3 project and  after set Android as target platform. Ok. But the problem is when i launch the debug.

With the Max Air for Android project everything works (so traces are ok), but with the Mobile AS3 project on FDT5 free, i always got the "player can't connect port 7935" error.

I added rules in the Windows Firewall (copied from the 3 rules of Flash Builder 4.5, so udp, tcp and generic for port 7935) and still i can't debug from my Samsung Galaxy S (the app is launched but i can't trace anything, so is pretty much hard work in this way).

The same happens on Snow Leopard.

Anybody with the same issue solved this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you receive this error the device itself you will have to grand the permissions to access internet to your application. In FDT Max you can easily do that via checkbox the [mobile properties](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Building_Mobile_Applications_With_FDT#Android_2). In FDT Free you will have to manually [add this permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) to your application discriptor, so the android section of your discriptor looks like that:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  </manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

Comment: Yeah, is working now! I didn't think the Max version had the permission checked and the free had to be added manually! This limitation sometimes drive me crazy, link this time. Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is the JIRA ticket that explains a bit more. It's slated for the 5.1 release. http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-2451